# A visible notification

Tags: android

I got an Android service running and occasionally show an important notification, which the user needs to close manually. I want the notification to show up in the center of the screen in unlocked phone state, and not as a tiny icon in the status bar. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of something like this:

1. in your manifest add permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

2. In your service:

```java
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
//...your adjustments...
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(...);
windowManager.addView(layout, params);
```